# Getting UnsatisfiedLinkError - please assist

Tags: java, exception, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I've got a 3rd party class file which I wrapped in a jar file, added the jar path to my project classpath and tried to use.

The class includes the following:

```
static
{
 _isloaded = false;
try
{
  Runtime.getRuntime().loadLibrary("some-dll-name (no extension!)");
  _isloaded = true;
}
 catch (Exception localException) {}catch (Error localError) {}
}
```

When I try to use this class from my code, I get the UnsatisfiedLinkError exception:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: lrapi1.vtc.connect(Ljava/lang/String;II)Z
> at lrapi1.vtc.connect(Native Method)
> at Actions.init(Actions.java:64)

From what I have read so far, it is probably that the dll cannot be found by the JVM.
So I put it in c:\windows\system32 and in my project source folder.

But still the exception is thrown.

Comment: Could you add full stack trace? Are you using 32-bit version of that dll with 32-bit JDK? (and vice versa for 64-bit)

Comment: Make sure your naming fits whatever the pattern is for Windows, ie, is there a standard prefix in the filename which (along with the .dll extension) should not be part of the library name you should pass to loadLibrary()?  For example, on unix you would load "libmylib.so" as "mylib"

Comment: Jakub, not much to add... java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: lrapi1.vtc.connect(Ljava/lang/String;II)Z                                                                                                                                                      at lrapi1.vtc.connect(Native Method)                                                                                                                                                      System.err:  at Actions.init(Actions.java:64)  I use a 32 bit dll with a 32 bit JDK

Comment: Chris, I hardly understood you. Sorry... The dll full name is vtclient32.dll and the LoadLibrary parameter is vtclient32

Comment: Guys, Thank you all for your attention. It was a DLL positioning issue. I guess... Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a DLL positioning issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `"some-dll-name (no extension!)"` with the full path to the `dll` file with the extension, for example: `Runtime.getRuntime().loadLibrary("C:/Windows/System32/crypt32.dll");` as explained here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/runtime_loadlibrary.htm

Comment: Thanks Boris, Well this change yield me the an exception even before, when I merely tried to create the object of the class where the static code exists.   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: lrapi1/vtc                                                                                                                                                      
at Actions.init(Actions.java:62)                                                                                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lrapi1.vtc